# SQL Query: How many worst cells do I need to exclude to achieve 90% success rate

Tags: mysql, sql

Table 1: cell_level

```
|Cell  |Success   |Attempts  |Success_rate  |Region  |Date     |
+------+----------+----------+--------------+--------+---------+
|A     |4         | 5        |80            |LGS     |Oct 13   |
|B     |3         | 5        |60            |LGS     |Oct 13   |
|C     |5         | 5        |100           |LGS     |Oct 13   |
|D     |1         | 5        |20            |LGS     |Oct 13   |
|E     |4         | 5        |80            |LGS     |Oct 13   |
|F     |2         | 5        |40            |LGS     |Oct 13   |
```

Table 2: region_level

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|Success   |Attempts  |Success_rate  |Region  |Date
-----------------------------------------------------
|19        |30        |63.33         |LGS     |Oct 13
```

I need an SQL query to determine the number of worst cells (in cell_level) to exclude in order to achieve 90% Success_rate on the region_level.

Worst cells are cells with the highest number of failures (ie Attempts - success).

Expected query output result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Date     |Success_rate  |Success_rate_with_exclusion  |Region    |Num_of_worst_cells_excluded_to_achieve_90
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Oct 13   |63.33         |90                           |LGS       |4
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like you have your work cut out for you... no seriously what attempts have you made?

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle for the lazy: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f5f2a/2

Comment: Question: what about if it's impossible to achieve a 90% success rate by removing any number of cells?  How should the query handle [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)?

Comment: Only the top worst cell(s) should be removed not just any number of cells.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the make up of the result set - but (and maybe by coincidence) this query gets that answer...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (Cell  CHAR(1) NOT NULL
 ,Success   INT NOT NULL 
 ,Attempts  INT NOT NULL
 ,Success_rate  INT NOT NULL
 ,Region  CHAR(3) NOT NULL
 ,Date     VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('A',4,5,80 ,'LGS','Oct 13'),
 ('B',3,5,60 ,'LGS','Oct 13'),
 ('C',5,5,100,'LGS','Oct 13'),
 ('D',1,5,20 ,'LGS','Oct 13'),
 ('E',4,5,80 ,'LGS','Oct 13'),
 ('F',2,5,40 ,'LGS','Oct 13');

 SELECT date
      , MIN(running)
      , MAX(running)
      , region
      , SUM(running < .9) exclusions 
   FROM (
        SELECT x.* 
             , SUM(y.success)/SUM(y.attempts) running 
          FROM my_table x 
          JOIN my_table y 
            ON y.success_rate > x.success_rate 
            OR (y.success_rate = x.success_rate AND y.cell <= x.cell) 
         GROUP 
            BY x.success_rate
             , x.cell 
        HAVING running <= .9
        ) a
    GROUP 
       BY date
        , region;
 +--------+--------------+--------------+--------+------------+
 | date   | MIN(running) | MAX(running) | region | exclusions |
 +--------+--------------+--------------+--------+------------+
 | Oct 13 |       0.6333 |       0.9000 | LGS    |          4 |
 +--------+--------------+--------------+--------+------------+
```